# Is there any command to enable/disable a php extension from command line?

Tags: php

Is there any command to enable/disable a php extension easily  from command line? (php.ini)

Comment: No, but there are tools you can use to parse and modify the config (eg `awk`).

Comment: just let us know what you configure to disable extension in php.ini so that we can make is easy from command line

Comment: @RahulPatil I just comment `extension=x.so` to disable x.

Answer (score 30):

If you are using PHP5.4+ on Debian based distro you can use php5enmod to enable and php5dismod to disable PHP extensions.

Comment: Note this works by adding/removing links in /etc/php5/{apache2,cli,...}/conf.d/

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierVares This comment was the really relevant information here.

Comment: `phpenmod` is only available for root users, because it's located in `/usr/sbin`

Answer (score 21):

You can enable an extension from the command line using:

```
php -d extension=/path/to/extension.so
```

`-d` is used to pass ini values via the command line. Unfortunately there is no way to disable an extension on the command line if it has been configured in the `php.ini` file. (You can follow the other answers of course but there is nothing you can do using `-d` or whatever option of the `php` command.)

Answer (score 12):

On Lubuntu I needed `pdo_sqlite`.

Enable manually:

```
$ sudo php5enmod pdo_sqlite
```

If doesn't work check:

```
$ ls /etc/php5/mods-available
```

The result list was missing `pdo_sqlite.ini`. We have to install it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

Or for php7:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7-sqlite3
```

Extension `sqlite3` is auto-enabled in CLI and in Apache during installation process, and now we have `mods-available`: `pdo_sqlite.ini`, `sqlite3.ini`.

Disable extension with:

```
$ sudo php5dismod pdo_sqlite
```

Comment: You can also use straight `phpenmod` and `phpdismod` without version number. After this you may need to restart apache server

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `-n` and then to append each needed extension using `-dextension`

Example:

```
php -n -dextension=json.so -dextension=phar.so composer.phar update
```

Comment: the order of the argument is not relevant. you can also do `php -d extension=json.so -d extension=phar.so -n composer.phar update` Or mix -d around -n. I tested this while I had to hack openssl.so back into pecl command via PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify `-n` to avoid any extensions loading from `php.ini`. This can improve some performance when you're using some (e.g. XDebug). E.g.

```
php -n -r "phpinfo();"
```

Comment: Any way to prevent loading an extension (like memcached) from loading, on a hosted server, although it is set up initially? I don't control my host setup, just the scripts on it. I'm suspecting it is somehow messing up with my sessions and would like to make sure it is off since I don't really use it..

Comment: Note, this blocks loading ALL settings from php.ini

Answer (score 4):

usage: phpenmod [ -v ALL|php_version ] [ -s ALL|sapi_name ] module_name [ module_name_2 ]

So use phpenmod -s cli yourextension

Comment: This command is used in newer Debian versions, like Stretch, where PHP5/PHP7 can be run side-by-side.

Comment: `phpenmod` is usually only available for root users, because it's located in `/usr/sbin`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
sed -i.bkp 's/^extension=x.so/# extension=x.so/' /path/of/php.ini && /etc/init.d/httpd reload
```

-i.bkp take backup as php.php.bkp and write in to original file

&& if first command is success then reload httpd service.

but I just notice that sed giving exit status 0 when search patter not match
so you can use

```
php_ini=/path/of/php.ini
__module=x.so
grep -q "^extension=$__module" $php_ini && { 
        sed -i.bkp "s/^extension=$__module/# extension=$__module/" $php_ini && 
        echo /etc/init.d/httpd reload; } || echo "cannot make requested change"
```

Or you can use below script for the enable and disable :

```
#!/bin/bash

php_ini=/path/of/php.ini
__module="$2"


[[ ! -f $php_ini ]] && { echo "Error: Can not found $php_ini" >&2; 
                         echo "Please define php.ini path in $php_ini"; 
                         exit 1; }

[[  -z $__module ]] && { echo "Error: Please Type Module Name:" >&2; 
                          exit 1; }

show_help(){
cat <<_EOF
        Usage:    To enable :
                  $0 -ie  <modulename>

                  To disable :
                  $0 -id  <modulename>

        example:
                  $0 -i xyz.so
_EOF

}

do_enable() {
grep -Eq "# extension=$__module$" $php_ini && {
sed -i.bkp "s/^# extension\=$__module$/extension=$__module/" $php_ini &&
echo /etc/init.d/httpd reload; echo "Changes Successfully Done"; } || echo "cannot make requested change"
}

do_disable() {
grep -q "^extension=$__module" $php_ini && {
sed -i.bkp "s/^extension=$__module/# extension=$__module/" $php_ini &&
echo /etc/init.d/httpd reload; echo "Changes Successfully Done"; } || echo "cannot make requested change"
}

Main() {

case $1 in
        -ie) do_enable ;;
        -id) do_disable ;;
         *) show_help ;;
esac
}

Main $*
```

Comment: Extension could also be added in `conf.d/*.ini` files. Maybe some modification needs to be done ?

Comment: Yes, we need to do changes for the same, have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0):

[Please Check this](https://tecadmin.net/enable-disable-php-modules-ubuntu/)

All the installed PHP modules configuration files are available under /etc/php/PHP_VERSION/mods-available directory